# Initialize an N-sized std::vector with std::uniform_real_distribution<double>

Tags: c++, random, stl, stdvector, uniform-initialization

I have a `std::vector<double> x`, who's size I do not know at compile time. Assuming the size of the vector is `N`, I want to assign `N` uniformly distributed random values to it. I currently do this within a loop

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution_pos(0.0,1.0);
for (auto it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); it++)
{
  *it = distribution_pos(generator);
}
```

This doesn't seem very elegant to me, so I was wondering if there was a smarter way to do this?

Comment: You can use range iteration: `for (auto &v:x) v=distribution_pos(generator);`

Comment: If you want to go more functional - and especially if you're in modern C++ with lambdas (for syntax ease) you can use [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate).

Comment: @davidbak since they're using the `<random>` library, they must have at least C++11, which means lambdas.

Comment: OK @Brian though of course `std::generate` will work with any generating function, not just the OP's specific example or `<random>`, in case anyone's interested ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `std::generate`:

```
std::vector<double> x(10);

std::default_random_engine gen{std::random_device{}()};
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);

std::generate(std::begin(x), std::end(x), [&]{ return dist(gen); });
```

**Note:**

You need to seed your random number generator otherwise you'll get the same sequence of numbers each time.

I don't recommend `std::default_random_engine` because the Standard does not guarantee quality or reproducibility across implementations or compiler versions.

Comment: Is there a reason you use a lambda instead of `std::bind(dist, gen)`?

Comment: When you say don't use `std::default_random_engine`, does adding `{std::random_device{}()}` guarantee reproducibility?

Comment: Also is there any significance to `[&]`, i.e., capture by reference in this application?

Comment: @BradyDean Lambda's are much more efficient than `std::bind`.

Comment: @Iamanon the `std::random_device` just adds a random seed. I makes sure the results are different every time. For reproducibility you would have to use a fixed seed but **not** with `std::default_random_engine`.

Comment: @Iamanon `[&]` tells the compiler to "capture" any necessary variables by *reference*. So it can access the variables `dist` and `gen` by reference.

Comment: Ah I see. What would you recommend using instead of `std::default_random_engine` when I want to use a fixed seed/reproduce?

Comment: @Iamanon `std::mt19937` is good quality and reasonably fast. But literally **any** of the other (named) predefined random number generators will give reproducibility across platforms as they specify the specific algorithm in the standard. See the list of predefined random number generators here  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Answer (score 3):

You could use `std::generate` like the following:

```
// First create an instance of an engine.
random_device rnd_device;

// Specify the engine and distribution.
mt19937 mersenne_engine {rnd_device()};  // Generates random doubles
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist (0, 1.0);

auto gen = [&dist, &mersenne_engine](){
               return dist(mersenne_engine);
           };

std::vector<double> x(N);
std::generate(begin(x), end(x), gen);
```

<kbd>See [`demo`](https://rextester.com/VAS34213)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `std::generate` or `std::generate_n` as:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::generate(std::begin(x), std::end(x), [&] {
    return distribution_pos(generator);
});

std::generate_n(std::begin(x), N, [&] {
    return distribution_pos(generator);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to reserve memory in the vector beforehand then this will work.

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
  std::vector<double> x;
  const int n = 10;

  std::default_random_engine gen(std::random_device{}());
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
  std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(x), n, [&]{ return dist(gen); });
}
```